# Rescue Exception with messages

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling

I get exception `Thrift::TransportException (end of file reached)` and I want to rescue it with the message("end of file reached").

Now I do

```
begin
  #...
rescue Thrift::TransportException => e
  raise e unless "end of file reached" == e.message
  # do whatever if it is not end of file reached.
end
```

Is there any method to do this rubyish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it can be avoided, don't depend on the message for logic - messages are just text and the developers of Thrift are free to change them at any given point in time, breaking your app.

`TransportException` in Thrift has a `type`, which is one of the constants you can see [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/thrift/0.5.0/Thrift/TransportException). The one relevant for you is `END_OF_FILE`.

As for the implementation in code, there is no better way to check a property of the exception than doing it in the `rescue` block, so:

```
begin
  #...
rescue Thrift::TransportException => e
  raise e unless e.type == Thrift::TransportException::END_OF_FILE
  # do whatever if it is not end of file reached.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `raise` in a `rescue` block, i'll suggest take an instance variable show it wherever you want.Also, `1==a` is very ugly, it's like `blue is a sky`

```
begin
  #...
rescue Thrift::TransportException => e
  @error = e.message if e.message == "end of file reached"
  # do whatever if it is not end of file reached.
end
```

Comment: As I understand the question, Sayuj WANTS to (re)raise the exception if it does not fit a certain criteria...

Comment: Yes. I want to re-raise unless end_of_file.